# How to remove seek bar from exoplayer

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer

I am using Exo Player [wrapper library](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) to integrate a video. All i need is to disable seekbar from the video.

I tried `videoView.setMediaController(null);`, but exo player does not have `MediaController`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply by creating a layout named: `exo_playback_control_view.xml`  and override the regular XML.

On this one below is the standard XML, You can add `android:visiblite="invisible"` for `DefaultTimeBar` which is what I think you're trying to hide, if not feel free change it as you want.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_repeat_toggle"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

EDIT: For your library you might wanna try to override the [appropriate layout](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia/blob/master/library/src/main/res/layout/exomedia_default_controls_mobile.xml) and override it. I'm not sure if it'll work but it is worth the shot.

1. Create the layout (`layout-21` etc... if needed) with the same file name.
2. Find the component you want to hide, I think it might be `android:id="@+id/exomedia_controls_video_seek"`
3. Add `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: Thanks @Biscuit, i have added this layout, can you please guide me on how to update the layout

Comment: You want to hide the `com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar` if I understand your question correctly so you just need to add `android:visibility="invisible"` in this node and it should work

Comment: Yes,i need to hide that, but its not effecting, may be because i am not using exoplayer directly, but `brianwernick ExoMedia` wrapper

Comment: Thanks :) , I just switched to Exo Player for testing, and able to remove the  seek bar by following your example.For `exo_ffwd` and other buttons `.GONE` was not working, so i just removed those buttons, I was afraid, that it may get crashed, but it didn't. Thanks again for your time :)