# How to add a feedback button to Android Exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

How to add a feedback button to Android Exoplayer 2. I cannot add any action buttons.

I followed many tutorials like:
https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a
But when looking for how to add an action button all I find is overriding existing play/pause like buttons. And it is impossible to modify ActivityPlayer.xml;

ps: I have no starting point ...

Comment: one way is to add the exoplayer as module to your project and modify the xml file as per your need and use it. did you try this?

Comment: I will search for how to achieve this, I hope this is not tedious. Do you have any demonstration resource for this ?

Comment: Currently I do not have any demonstration for this, but I have modified the exo player xml in past and have added my own controls

Comment: it seems they give out of the box controls like shown here https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/customizing-exoplayers-ui-components-728cf55ee07a but I don't know how to add any arbitrary action.

Comment: that link indeed points you to the link I have mentioned. Try to follow the steps mentioned in my answer that might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can look at my answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60837124/how-to-remove-seek-bar-from-exoplayer/60840958#60840958) and instead of removing a node you can add one.

Also you can take a look at my github [repo](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin) where I've done a few tweaks to the layout. It might help you understand how to change it.

Comment: I will check this and come back with results

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. Go to the [Exoplayer repository](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Add the `exoplayer` as module. In Library folder you have a folder UI in the layout files of that folder you can find xml files for controls that are present in exo player.

Since you are adding it as module you can modify default the exo player xml and add your own controls.

You can include this exo player as project in your application `gradle` instead of normal dependency.

Hope this helps. Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I will try this and come back.

Comment: Sure. Will be eager to see if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the whole project from [Github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

add the whole project as a module in your project, then go the layout folder and add your button into respective layout file.